# All combinations by keeping order (taking repetition into account)

Tags: permutations, combinations

Lets say **A** is an ordered list contains of elements `[a,a,b,a,c]`. I want to get all combinations of elements by sequential order like `(a,a) (a,b) (b,a) (b,c)`. But `(c,a)` or `(c,b)` cannot be part of this. Is there any easy method to formulate this ? Also I want to keep count of every combination occurrence. For example:

```
(a,a) - 3 times
(a,b) - 2 times
```

etc.